# Неправильно отображается сайт на мобильном телефоне

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер.

Проблема в том, что на мобильнике как-то неправильно работает viewport
( http://akotov.ru/works/nails/ ), но на мобильнике как-то не так:

[image]

Подскажите, как можно это пофиксить? Все перепробовал.

**Обновление**

Контент странички должен центрироваться. Но почему-то этого не происходит, приложил скриншот. Попытался поиграться с вьюпортом, все равно не работает.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: У вас же сайт неадаптивный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.wrapp { width: 960px;}
```

Вы сами себе сделали так, либо ставьте scale, либо убирайте ширину врапера, либо для каждого устройства ставьте свою ширину врапера. Почитайте про media CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp